# Swift handle did select on multiple annotations on same location

Tags: swift

I'm trying to call a function when annotations of the same location are selected. All I'm aiming for is to call a function and show a view controller with the two restaurants but for some reason, the function below isn't being called when I selected the marker in the image. (It works fine for single annotations). Thanks for any help.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    guard let anno = view.annotation as? MyAnno else { return }

    print(anno.post)
}
```

[image]

Comment: why use guard statement here? it's call but can not reach ` print(anno.post)`  set the all annotation in a array object and intreating the array check with   `view.annotation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your guard statement. As I could find out in a short research, iOS uses a [MKClusterAnnotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkclusterannotation) type for annotations that are equally located. Thus, the `view` variable does not have a `.annotation` set that confirms to your custom subclass.

In this case you need to try to cast it to a `MKClusterAnnotation` object, which in return has a property `.memberAnnotations` of type `[MKAnnotation]`, which is what you want.

I think your code should look something like this (haven't tested it though):

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let anno = view.annotation as? MyAnno {
         print("Single Annotation selected:")        
         print(anno.post)

         // do anything
         return
    }

    if let anno = view.annotation as? MKClusterAnnotations {
        let selection: [MKAnnotation] = anno.memberAnnotations
        print("\(selection.count) Annotations selected:")

        // do something with your annotation group
        // you should now also be able to cast to your MyAnno class again 
        for item in selection {
            if let myAnno = item as? MyAnno {
                print(myAnno.post)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

For further information also take a look at [Decluttering a Map with MapKit Annotation Clustering](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering).